# Replacing string

Tags: r, string

My intention is: (1) to extract multiwords/strings (from `data1`), (2) to replace those extracted words by other strings located in another dataset (`data2`). To make it clear, the objective is replacing `mult1` by `mult2` after mining `mult1` from `data1`.

```
library(sringi)
library(stringr)
data1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
          text=c("This is text mining exercise text",
                 "Text analysis is bit confusing analyssi",
                 "Hint on this text analysis?")) 
data2 <- data.frame(mult1 = c("text","analysis","bit confusing"),
          mult2 = c("A; B; C","A; D", "A; B; C; D"))
txt <- subf <- list()
for(i in 1:length(data1$id)){ 
    txt[i] <- str_extract_all(data1$text[i],str_c(data2$mult1,collapse="|")) #this works fine
    subf[i] <- str_replace_all(txt[i],data2$mult2[i]) #here is my problem
}
```

For intance, `txt[1]` give:

```
[1] "text" "text"
```

The corresponding string for `text` is `"A; B; C"` in this case.What I'm looking for is the code that can produce an ouput like:

```
"A; B; C" "A; B; C"
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is a problem of the type described in [this famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el).

```
txt <- subf <- list()
pattern <- tolower(str_c(data2$mult1, collapse = "|"))
for(i in 1:length(data1$id)){ 
  txt[[i]] <- unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(data1$text[i]), pattern))
  j <- match(txt[[i]], data2$mult1)
  subf[[i]] <- data2$mult2[j]
}
subf
#[[1]]
#[1] "A; B; C" "A; B; C"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "A; B; C"    "A; D"       "A; B; C; D"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "A; B; C" "A; D"
```

Comment: You nailed it. Big thanks! Is that possible to produce a frequency `table` after removing semicolon for `subf[[i]]`?

Comment: @Gadaa A one-liner `table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(unlist(subf), ';'))))`?

Comment: It gives an error which says `non-character argument`. When I use `as.character`, it produces an output which is something different. I appreciate it if you check it back for me.

Comment: @Gadaa Can you post the output you are getting?

Comment: Sure! `Error in strsplit(unlist(subf), ";") : non-character argument`.

Comment: @Gadaa `strsplit(as.character(unlist(subf)), ";")`. But this becomes more and more complicated and unreadable, it would be better to break the code into 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: I checked back the original code you drafted. The code is conceptually right. But the line `subf[[i]] <- rep(data2$mult2[i], length(txt[[i]]))` consider only the first element of `txt[[i]]`. Would kindly check it & try to include the other elements of `txt[[i]]`, please? Tnx!

Comment: @Gadaa I believe I've got it, see the edit. I have also changed the code to match strings case-insensitive by converting to lower case first.

Comment: Many thanks for being concerned. That's perfectly what I need!

Comment: I come to you once again! The value of `j` kept fixed & do not change in each iteration as expected. This has an impact on the `subf[[i]] <- data2$mult2[j]`. Would you kindly check it once again, please?